# Как сравнить класс и список по критериям?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть класс **DB**

```
 class DB
 {
   private List<string> newList;
   public string Naimenovanie { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

В дальнейшем я использую `List<DB> listDB = new List<DB>();` чтобы в цикле вставлять экземпляры класса DB.

Есть также отдельно список `List<string> urls = new List<string>();`

```
1) Как удалить элементы listDB, которых нет в urls?
2) Как добавить элементы в listDB, которые есть в urls?
3) Если элементы есть и в listDB и в urls - то его не трогаем
```

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! 
В качестве решения первой задачи предлагаю:

```
var listToDelete = listDB.Where(list=>!urls.Contains(list.Url)).ToList();
listDB.RemoveRange(listToDelete);
```

Первым этапом выбираете элементы, которых нет в списке urls. Затем полученный список удаляете из основного.

Вторая задача (если я вас правильно поняла):

```
foreach(var url in urls){
listDB.Add(new DB(){
    Url = url
});
}
```

По идее, после этих операций список listDB будет содержать только те элементы, которые есть в urls

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = urls.Select(x=>listDB.FirstOrDefault(y=>y.Url == x)??new DB{Url = x}).ToList();
```

Если лист большой, то сначала создайте словарь.

```
var cache = listDB.ToDictionary(x=>x.Url, x=>x);
var result = urls.Select(x=>cache.ContainsKey(x)?cache[x]:new DB{Url = x}).ToList();
```